# elasticsearch - how to correctly point an alias to an index?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am creating an elasticsearch index with a timestamp and pointing an alias to it.

Like: indexname = index-201512302002515529, alias = index

So if I need to reindex, I would create a new index (with another timestamp), point the alias to it when indexing is finished and remove the old index.

The process works, but I always get ZERO hits when searching the index with the alias name.

I use the alias name on SetDefaultIndex() of the connection settings.

To create the index:

```
    var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
    var indexName = string.Concat(containerName, "-", timeStamp);

    CreateIndex(indexName);
    Console.WriteLine($"Creating index {indexName}...");

    //do the indexing
    Console.WriteLine("Indexing from Database...");
    IndexAllFromDb();

    //delete aliases
    if (cli.AliasExists(containerName).Exists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting Aliases...");
        foreach (var index in cli.GetIndicesPointingToAlias(containerName))
        {
            cli.Alias(a => a
                .Remove(remove => remove
                    .Index(index)
                    .Alias(containerName)
                )
            );
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Creating Aliases...");
    //create the alias
    cli.Alias(a => a
        .Add(add => add
            .Index(indexName)
            .Alias(containerName)
        )
    );
```

CreateIndex(indexName) creates all the mappings and the analysis settings.
IndexAllFromDB() reads an SQL database and do the indexing.

I am using this code to connect:

```
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(connectionString));
    settings.SetDefaultIndex(SiteSettings.Settings.SearchContainerName);

    var cli = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

If i create the index directly with the alias name it works, so I am probably doing something wrong with the alias....

Thanks.

Comment: I've found the .NET libraries for interacting with ElasticSearch to be awkward and clumsy.  I've had better luck with Python and [the request library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), since I can just send GETs and POSTs and process the JSON almost natively.  This is despite the fact that I don't know Python and have to look up the syntax as I go.

With this approach you could just send the atomic alias change command from [the ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html).

Comment: Yes, the REST API for ElasticSearch is very good, and there's heaps of documentation and community content around it.  You can use it in .NET by posting JSON (as a string) using WebClient.  If you're happy to get away from .NET you can also use Invoke-RestMethod in PowerShell.

Comment: Can you check GET/containerName/_mapping ?

Is it shows your index name with timestamp?

Comment: From first looks, nothing seems wrong with the code. Can you check the value of `GET <value of indexName>/_aliases/<value of containerName>`? That should give a hint as to what is not working.

Comment: LMK: It shows the index name with the timestamp and all the mappings.

Comment: bittusarkar: It shows the index name with the timestamp and the alias. Seems to be correct.

Comment: UPDATE: Found the problem, IndexAllFromDB() should use the new index, it was indexing on the old index. So when the alias was pointed to the new index, it was empty.. Ooops... rookie mistake.. hehe.. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Using the alias name as the default index on `ConnectionSettings` is fine; two potential things that I can see with your current approach other than the mistake that you found mentioned in the comments:

- you are removing aliases one at a time and then adding the alias to the new index. These operations can be performed atomically in one operation
- the default refresh interval for shards in an index is 1 second and you therefore may be searching before this refresh. You may want to consider refreshing after all of the indexing has finished to ensure that newly indexed documents appear in search results.

I've pulled together this example that may help you get going

```
void Main()
{
    var containerName = "index";

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
        .SetDefaultIndex(containerName)
        .ExposeRawResponse(true)
        .SetConnectionStatusHandler(response =>
        {
            // log out the requests
            if (response.Request != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} \n{2}\n", response.RequestMethod.ToUpperInvariant(), response.RequestUrl,
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.Request));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}\n", response.RequestMethod.ToUpperInvariant(), response.RequestUrl);
            }

            if (response.ResponseRaw != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}\n{1}\n\n{2}\n", response.HttpStatusCode, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseRaw), new String('-', 30));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}\n\n{1}\n", response.HttpStatusCode, new String('-', 30));
            }
        });

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
    var indexName = string.Concat(containerName, "-", timeStamp);

    var indexResponse = client.CreateIndex(indexName, c => c
        .AddMapping<Item>(m => m
            .MapFromAttributes()
        )
    );

    //do the indexing
    Console.WriteLine("Indexing from Database...");
    IndexAllFromDb(client, indexName);

    // add alias to the new index
    var aliasDescriptor = new AliasDescriptor()
        .Add(add => add.Alias(containerName).Index(indexName));

    // get any existing indices that have the alias
    Console.WriteLine($"Get existing indices with alias '{containerName}'");
    var aliasesResponses = client.GetAliases(a => a.Alias(containerName));

    foreach (var index in aliasesResponses.Indices)
    {
        if (index.Value.Any(a => a.Name == containerName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Removing alias from index '{index.Key}'");
            aliasDescriptor.Remove(remove => remove.Alias(containerName).Index(index.Key));
        }
    }

    // atomic add and delete
    var aliasResponse = client.Alias(aliasDescriptor);

    var countResponse = client.Search<Item>(s => s.SearchType(SearchType.Count));

    Console.WriteLine($"{countResponse.Total} items");
}

private static void IndexAllFromDb(IElasticClient client, string indexName)
{
    var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(i => Item.Create(i));

    // refresh shards manually as opposed to relying on the refresh interval
    // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-refresh
    var indexManyResponse = client.Bulk(b => b.IndexMany(items, (bi, i) => bi.Index(indexName).Document(i)).Refresh());
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static Item Create(int id)
    {
        return new Item { Id = id, Name = "Item " + id };
    }
}
```

Running this the second time (to ensure there is an existing index with the alias applied) yields the following results

```
POST http://localhost:9200/index-201601011621518238 
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {}
  },
  "mappings": {
    "item": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Status: 200
{"acknowledged":true}

------------------------------

Indexing from Database...
POST http://localhost:9200/_bulk?refresh=true 
{ "index" :  {"_index":"index-201601011621518238","_type":"item","_id":"1"} }
{"id":1,"name":"Item 1"}
// ... cut out for brevity
{ "index" :  {"_index":"index-201601011621518238","_type":"item","_id":"1000"} }
{"id":1000,"name":"Item 1000"}


Status: 200
{"took":124,"errors":false,"items":[{"index":{"_index":"index-201601011621518238","_type":"item","_id":"1","_version":1,"status":201}},
// ... cut out for brevity
{"index":{"_index":"index-201601011621518238","_type":"item","_id":"1000","_version":1,"status":201}}]}
------------------------------

Get existing indices with alias 'index'
GET http://localhost:9200/_aliases/index

Status: 200
{"index-201601011616271553":{"aliases":{"index":{}}},"index-201601011621518238":{"aliases":{}}}

------------------------------

Removing alias from index 'index-201601011616271553'
POST http://localhost:9200/_aliases 
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "index-201601011621518238",
        "alias": "index"
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "index": "index-201601011616271553",
        "alias": "index"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Status: 200
{"acknowledged":true}

------------------------------

POST http://localhost:9200/index/item/_search?search_type=count 
{}

Status: 200
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1000,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]}}

------------------------------

1000 items
```